# Is it bad practice to use local variables as switches in sql queries

Tags: t-sql, user-defined-functions, sql-server-2014

I have a dynamic sql query in a stored procedure which I'm supposed to convert to a Table Valued Function (TVF).
The string is being built using code like the following:

```
 Declare @str = 'select * from tableName where table = ''words'''
 If @flag = 'ONE'
      set @str = @str + 'AND year_id = '+@year_id
 ELSE
 If @flag = 'TWO'
      set @str = @str + 'AND record_id = '+@record_id

 set @str = @str + 'order by year_id, record_id'
 exec (@str)
```

In a TVF, you can't run an insert statement, so you can't return the results of this exec query to the user (to my knowledge at least, feel free to correct me).

In order to get around this limitation, I created a filter which is only applied if a local variable has a given value.

```
select * 
from tableName 
where table = 'words'
AND (
     (@flag = 'ONE' and year_id = @year_id)
    OR (@flag = 'TWO' and record_id = @record_id)
    )
Order by year_id, record_id
```

Now, it looks like this will work for simpler queries, but for more complex queries you would need to create a condition for each possible combination of dynamic sql strings.

With that restriction aside, are there any security and/or performance risks in writing queries in this manner?  Is there a simpler way to write a query like this for a TVF?

Comment: Why not create two functions, one for each flag? That is likely to get you the best performance.

Comment: There are actually 8 different possibilities in my query.  Having 8 different functions for roughly the same query seems clunky to me (and the maintenance would be prone to error).  This query will also be used by an existing report (and it would be preferable not to redesign the whole report to use multiple functions).  I thought the performance of the Table-valued-function might be an issue, but after testing, it appears to be comparable to the stored procedure.

Comment: To my mind, the query looks like it should be clunky.  And "smells" a little funny to me, but so far I can't figure out a reason why I shouldn't code it like this (hence the question).

Comment: Well, the `OR` will probably not allow the use of indices on any of the fields you are comparing with. You could slap a `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` in there to force an execution plan for only one condition, that can use any indices, but the recompile takes some time as well. Inspect the execution plan in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of translating the dynamic SQL into an ITVF is to eliminate this nonsense. Just write the ITVF as

```
create function schemaNme.funcName() returns table return
  select * from tableName where table = 'words';
```

and let the client add any desired  filtering criteria directly like this:

```
select *
from schemaNme.funcName()  t
where t.year_id = @year_id;
```

This hides the details of how the data is assembled into a logical view from the physical tables while still enabling the client to filter as desired.

*Update from my supplementary comment below*:

An ITVF is a parameterized view, possibly with a cached query plan. Like any other view (or table for that matter), if you wish to dynamically modify the access mechanism, as here, you will have to use dynamic SQL. However because the innards of the query are already encapsulated for you in the ITVF, you can in this case simply modify the WHERE clause dynamically, a somewhat simpler task

Comment: Could you point me to a place where this intention for the ITVF is expanded upon?

Comment: An ITVF is a parameterized view, possibly with a cached query plan. Like any other view (or table for that matter), if you wish to dynamically modify the access mechanism, as here, you will have to use dynamic SQL. However because the innards of the query are already encapsulated for you in the ITVF, you can in this case simply modify the WHERE clause dynamically, a somewhat simpler task.

Comment: Thanks for your help Pieter!